# prime number machine and if not working tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a machine that can recognize prime numbers individually and show the result to the user,But there is a problem that I showed in the text below

```
>>12
>>12,is a not prime number
>>7
>>7,is a not prime number
```

Which prime number and which composite number can be converted into composite numbers
my codes:

```
from tkinter import * 
def rso():
    a = int(text.get())
    for i in range(a + 1):
        pass
    if a % i == 1:
        Label(app,text=(a,"is a  prime number"),font=20).pack()
    else:
        Label(app,text=(a,"is a NOT prime number"),font=20).pack()
app = Tk()
text = Entry(app,font=20)
text.pack()
Button(app,text="sumbit",font=20,command=rso).pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1: Your for loop isn't doing anything at all if it's `pass`-ing on every iteration. 2: Instead of creating a new `Label` based on the outcome of `rso()`, you should declare your label in the global  scope after `app = Tk()` (e.g. `label = Label(app, text='result'`) and then *configure* that label within `rso` (e.g. `label.configure(text='is a prime number')`

Comment: What exactly do you think this does: `for i in range(a + 1): pass`? And do you think `if a % i == 1:` would correctly identify a prime after that? If you think about it, you're just testing if for some number `a`, `a % a == 1` - which of course is never true, as `a % a` is always `0`. Note that even if you used the loop value somehow, a prime is not defined as a "number that has remainder 1 when divided by any number between 0 and itself".

Comment: The simple but not efficient way to determine whether a positive `n` is a prime number: `n` is not 0 or 1 and `n` is not divisible by any number from 2 to n//2+1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
num = 3
flag = False

if num > 1:
    # check for factors
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            flag = True
            break

if flag:
    print(f"{num} is not a prime number")
else:
    print(f"{num} is a prime number")
```

Comment: In variable, just enter number. U can used input().

Comment: Note that 0 and 1 are not prime numbers in theory.  Your logic will identify them as prime numbers.